# transaction is not wholly rolled back

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

My problem is that I execute a transaction that embodies a few requests and if one of those requests fails, those that above don't get rolled back but they should. The transaction has the following structure (recommended in the official nestjs documentation):

```
    public async create(createUserDto: RegisterUserDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
        const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
        await queryRunner.connect();
        await queryRunner.startTransaction();
        try {
            const firstReqResult = await this.firstMethod(queryRunner, createUserDto);
            const secondReqResult = await this.secondMethod(firstReqResult, queryRunner);
            await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
            return secondReqResult;
        } catch (err) {
            await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
            throw new HttpException(err.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } finally {
            await queryRunner.release();
        }
    }
```

So if the first method writes some data to some data tables and the `secondMethod` method throws an error for some reason then that data is not removed on rollback and thus come orphan records in the DB.

One important thing: these two methods `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` are not transactions themselves, they are just ordinary methods that use the `queryRunner` passed to them as a parameter.

How to make `typeorm` roll back that kind of a transaction properly?

**EDIT**:

Seems like that attempt of mine didn't work. So I will post more details:

Here's the main method:

```
    public async create(createUserDto: RegisterUserDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
        const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
        await queryRunner.connect();
        await queryRunner.startTransaction();
        try {
            // some code
            const profilePrivacyPermissions = await this.profilePrivacyPermissionsService.generateInitSettings(queryRunner);
            const registeredUser = await this.registerUser(user);
            await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
            return registeredUser;
        } catch (err) {
            await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
            throw new HttpException(err.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } finally {
            await queryRunner.release();
        }
    }
```

The `registerUser` method throws exception.

The generateInitSettings method looks like so:

```
    public async generateInitSettings(qr: QueryRunner): Promise<ProfilePrivacyEntity[]> {
        const generatedSettings = [];
        const screenTypeIds = Object.values(EScreenType).filter(value => typeof value === 'number') as number[];
        for (const stId of screenTypeIds) {
            const setting = this.createAndSaveInitSetting(stId, qr);
            generatedSettings.push(setting);
        }
        return await Promise.all(generatedSettings);
    }
```

and `createAndSaveInitSetting`:

```
    private async createAndSaveInitSetting(screenType: number, qr: QueryRunner): Promise<ProfilePrivacyEntity> {
        const permission = new ProfilePrivacyEntity();
        permission.setScreenType(screenType)
                  .setIsEverybody(true)
                  .setIsContacts(false)
                  .setIsNobody(false);
        const createdPermission = qr.manager.getRepository(ProfilePrivacyEntity).create(permission);
        return await createdPermission.save();
    }
```

So when the `registerUser` method throws an exception the DB changes made by `generateInitSettings` are not rolled back.

Comment: What DB are you using? Can you provide the implementation (more specifically the calls on the `queryRunner`) in `this.firstMethod` and `this.secondMethod`?

Comment: I'm using PostreSQL, as for the implementation, I will try to think something up and when I do I will post it here, cos the original methods are pretty complicated. I had the same issue with other more simple methods.

Comment: Add some code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @jeeves hmm I seem to have managed to fix this issue, the problem was that one of the methods didn't receive the queryRunner transaction context. It seems to work now, but anyway, I won't delete this question until I'm certain that I've fixed the bug, if not, I will try to post the minimum of code sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @jeeves Hey, it turned out that that solution didn't work, it made me think it did for one reason but then I found out that the behaviour was incorrect. I posted the details. Would you please, have a look?

Comment: Is the error definitely going to the catch block i.e. `this.registerUser` is definitely not catching the error?

Comment: I'll have to try and replicate this.

Comment: Yes, it is and typeorm logs the rollback in the console but the thing is that it doesn't happen for the generateInitSettings method.

Comment: @jeeves Hi, have you tried anything? :)

Comment: Not yet. What DB and version are you using?

Comment: @jeeves It's PostgreSQL 12.3.

Comment: @jeeves hey, any updates?